# Hot reloading in React Redux Bundled code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, gulp, redux

I have a project written in typeScript using the react and redux framework. I am aware of webpack and how it uses certain middleware libraries to enable hot reloading.

Here begins my question. My code (written in typescript) essentially is first converted into jsx using certain gulp tasks. Later this code is bundled using webpack's functionality.(Let's combine these 2 steps and call it compilation for convenience) If I am to use webpack HotReloadMiddleware, will it also need my entire code to be "re-compiled". If that is the case then it doesn't do something radically different as compared to compiling the code manually and running it again.

So to boil it down my problem is that I have to recompile the entire code inorder to get an updated bundle file. 
Is there any library out there that solves this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this template

[JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) There is project base on Typescript, webpack and Hot module replacement. Its good start point that worked for me.